# Limiting files with wget

Tags: shell, wget

I'm trying to download mailing list archives such as

http://cryolist.org/archives/

In particular, I have a page and would like to download every file linked from that page which ends with ".txt.gz". Is there a way to restrict wget to do this? Failing that, an alternate approach?

### References

http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
wget \
    --recursive \
    --no-directories \
    --no-parent \
    --level 1 \
    --accept .txt.gz \
    --execute robots=off \
    http://lists.cryolist.org/pipermail/cryolist-cryolist.org/
```

*Using long options for readability.*

Answer (score 3):

From `wget --help`:

```
-r,  --recursive          specify recursive download.
-l,  --level=NUMBER       maximum recursion depth (inf or 0 for infinite).
-A,  --accept=LIST        comma-separated list of accepted extensions.
```

Keeping in mind that the files are linked to in the iFrame [lists.cryolist.org/pipermail/cryolist-cryolist.org](http://lists.cryolist.org/pipermail/cryolist-cryolist.org), the following command will produce the desired results:

```
wget -r -l1 -A "txt.gz" lists.cryolist.org/pipermail/cryolist-cryolist.org
```

#### Switches

- The `-r` switch makes download other resources that are linked to.
- The `-l1` switch limits this to one level, i.e., if `page1` links to `page2` and `page2` links to `unwanted.txt.gz`, this file will not be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Write a bash script, Store all the months in an array, loop though them inserting them in to the wget command at the correct position